Why can't get proper value in the cell?
The value in cell A2 is xxxx,i want to print it:
Sub Main
Dim oSheet as Object
Dim oCell as Object
oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getActiveSheet()
oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A2")
x = oCell.getValue()
print x   
End Sub

Why the result of x is 0 ,instead of xxxx?

What you want is the getString method, not getValue. Since you are returning a string/text data type and not numerical, use getString.
Updated code:
Sub Main
Dim oSheet as Object
Dim oCell as Object
oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.getActiveSheet()
oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A2")
x = oCell.getString()
print x   
End Sub

